# gdb giving a function name followed by a number instead of file and line number

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I have a segmentation fault in my program, and I'm using `gdb` to identify where it's happening. However, I am not able to see a clear line number where the error is occurring.

Below is a screenshot of my output.

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> [Switching to Thread 20065168 (LWP 4645)]
> 0x007e537f in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
> (gdb) backtrace
> #0  0x007e537f in _int_free () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #1  0x007e90f0 in free () from /lib/libc.so.6
> #2  0x080d9e67 in CRYPTO_free ()
> #3  0xbfd15f7c in ?? ()
> #4  0xbfd16108 in ?? ()
> #5  0x08070b3e in function_random.19532 ()
> #6  0x00000001 in ?? ()
> #7  0x00000000 in ?? ()
> (gdb)
> ```

`frame 5` is the piece of code that I have written, but I don't quite understand what it means.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Thank you for using `gdb` to find out the root cause of SF instead of posting a dump of code here. :-) +1

Comment: Hey @SouravGhosh, can you explain the edits you made to the question? What exactly does the yellow box surrounding my output signify?

Comment: Nothing special, it only implies that the posted block is not a `code`, it's some sort of _output_. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, in your case, debug symbols are not present in the binary. That is why, `gdb` is not able to read the *debugging* info and display them.

Re-compile your code, with the debugging enabled.

Example: for `gcc`, use the `-g` options.